# Django Manual Debugging Process Flow

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am in the processing of developing a Django application. I had spent around 40-50 hours researching Django, and I am well on my way to making an application!

However, I am starting to come across "more serious" errors, as some might call them, as I am not able to figure out from my stack trace exactly what the real problem is.

Basically, I click a link on my page, and this error pops up:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    /accounts/profile/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
***The view userprofile.views.user_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object.***

That leads me to believe the error is in my views file, except that I was following a tutorial line for line, and I am led to believe the error might be in how forms.py is being used to create the HttpResponse object.

The code in short, is,

```
form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
...
args = {}
args.update(csrf(request)) // security token
args['form'] = form
return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

profile.html is also definitely fine, I tested that, and I am basically calling this from a loggedin.html page where I display a valid user login.

Thanks so much for your help SO, I don't usually ask questions, but I have been stuck on this problem alone for 5-6 development hours. Try not to mock me for not understanding this likely-simply but hidden-to-beginner error :)

Also, I would prefer in the response if you could indicate how you went about solving this error, especially indicating how my thinking is and where the root misunderstanding is.

And in your answers, only reference specific instances of the docs, because I've done plenty of searching, but perhaps it isn't narrowed down quite to what my issue is :D

Thanks again,

James

**Comment One: Tutorial**

[Here is the tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLRxkStiaUg) I am referring to.  I am getting stuck in identifying the bug, as I have all of the code and everything worked until I tried clicking the hyperlink. I am not experienced to *where* the error is coming from.

**Second Comment: Relevant Code**

**userprofile/views.py**

```
 def user_profile(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
       form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
       else:
          user = request.user
          profile = user.profile
          form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

       args = {}
       args.update(csrf(request)) // security token
       args['form'] = form
       return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

**myapp urls.py , userprofile urls.py**

```
(r'^accounts/', include ('userprofile.urls')),
...
url(r'^profile/$', 'userprofile.views.user_profile'),
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the tutorial you're following? And tell us which part of it you're stuck on?

Comment: Hi James. You're in good hands with Django ;) Would you mind posting the code for the entire view along with your urls.py?

Comment: I'm loving it so far. I just added the link and I'll add the code in a moment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's really your view code, it's a simple indentation error.  It should be:

```
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request)) // security token
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

What's going on is that when request.METHOD is `GET`, there's no `else` clause on the initial if, so the view function ends without returning anything.  Instead, you want to create the form, add it to the context, and render it - either because it's a `GET` request or because there were errors in the form, and you want to rerender the context to show those errors and allow the user to correct them.

Comment: I have tabspace set to 3... Or are you refering to args being ... not nested properly?

Comment: `args` and the whole creation of the form, yes - they're indented too far so they're only called when `request.method == 'POST'` and not `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a feeling it was something trivial like this. I was actually worried about the GET request myself. Thanks again.

Comment: One other thing that caught my eye - doublecheck your `urls.py` definition for `/accounts/loggedin`.  It's pretty common to require that URLs end with a trailing /, and if the `urls.py` file does for that view then your redirect on success is going to throw an exception.  You might need `/accounts/loggedin/` depending on how it's declared - although the eventual best approach is going to be to learn about other options for specifying where to redirect to, which I trust your tutorial will eventually cover.